# java end of stream using sytem.in.read

Tags: java, io

i just started java and was reading the java a beginners guide here it is mentioned 
"When reading from System.in pressing ENTER generates an end-of-stream condition"

and that the read method returns -1 when it attempts to read at the end of stream but pressing enter doesn't seem to do anything as read just assigns the value of the \n in Linux and value of \r \n separately in windows.

Comment: Could you also provide the link of the guide you are using?

Comment: Pressing enter doesn't close the input stream. You can observe this yourself by copy and pasting the bottom 5 lines (everything except the `data` declaration). It will still work the second time, because the stream is still open. It's system-specific but usually CTRL+D or CTRL+Z will close the stream.

Comment: yeah i have the java a beginners guide 7th edition https://www.amazon.com/Java-Beginners-Seventh-Herbert-Schildt/dp/1259589315

Comment: yeah i tried using the ctrl +z it worked after pressing enter , the reason i asked this is because i want to know misprinting in the book or i am i understanding it wrong

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because We don't answer question about quality of third party guides.